# Error when in Silverlight when trying to reach an RIA Services endpoint

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I created a Ria services endpoint. Silverlight passes data into the RIA Services. The end point then writes/updates this data to the file system. We are experiencing the following exception:

> System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException:
>   Invoke operation
>   'ModifyLogiDashletXmlFile' failed.
>   Exception of type
>   'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException'
>   was thrown.    at
>   Phoenix.UI.SL.Infrastructure.Services.LogiReportService.<>c_*DisplayClass8.<ModifyLogiDashletXmlFile>b*_7(InvokeOperation
>   operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.InvokeOperation.<>c_*DisplayClass4`1.&lt;Create&gt;b__0(InvokeOperation`1 arg)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.InvokeOperation`1.InvokeCompleteAction()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.OperationBase.Complete(Exception
>   error)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.InvokeOperation.Complete(Exception
>   error)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.CompleteInvoke(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.<>c*_DisplayClass38.<InvokeOperation>b__34(Object )

the attributes on the class:

```
[EnableClientAccess(RequiresSecureEndpoint = true)]
    [LinqToEntitiesDomainServiceDescriptionProvider(typeof(PhoenixEntities))] // IMPORTANT: Must have this because we are returning/passing EF Entities from Phoenix Context
    [RequiresAuthentication]
    public class LogiReportService : DomainService
    {
...

}
```

The entry method:

```
[Invoke]
public void ModifyLogiDashletXmlFile(IEnumerable<ParameterNameValuePair> paramNameValuePairs, Guid clientId, string dashletInstanceId)
{

    // Validate Client is has a valid relationship to the User (i.e. no disabled)
    if (this.PhoenixUser.MembershipClientIds.Contains(clientId))
    {
       ModifyLogiXmlFile(PhoenixUser.UserId, clientId.ToString(), dashletInstanceId, paramNameValuePairs);
    }
}
```

What's baffling is other endpoints work fine. The differences between this endpoint and the other is this one writes and reads files from the file-system. The app-domain user has full-rights and the error returned does not appear to be a permissions issue.

All idea's are welcomed. I'm hitting up against a wall with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue turned out to be a permissions issue on the server. A file was being written to the system.

RIA services was swallowing the error and presenting a generic error in it's stead. I put a try catch around the entry method and logged the error to the database. Then I was able to discover the real issue.